# thread.sleep(5000) is not working

Tags: java, multithreading

Actually I am working on a project which produces a dialogue on button click and dispose it in 5 sec via Thread.sleep(5000)
I have written following under run method

```
void showpopup(String p, String t) throws IOException {
    JPanel app = new JPanel();
    popup = new JFrame();
    // app.setSize(300,400);
    GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    app.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    app.setVisible(true);
    app.setBackground(new Color(39, 170, 225));

    popup.setUndecorated(true);
    popup.setSize(300, 100);
    popup.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    JLabel header = new JLabel();
    header.setText(p);
    c1.gridx = 0;
    c1.gridy = 0;
    c1.weightx = 1.0f;
    c1.weighty = 1.0f;
    c1.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    c1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    header.setFont(new Font("comfortaa", Font.BOLD, 15));
    app.add(header, c1);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.weightx = 0.3f;
    constraints.weighty = 0.3f;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    popup.add(app, constraints);

    BufferedImage Butico = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/utkarsh/Desktop/close.png"));
    JButton close = new JButton(new ImageIcon(Butico));
    close.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    close.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    c1.gridx = 1;
    c1.weightx = 0f;
    c1.weighty = 0f;
    c1.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    c1.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    close.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            popup.dispose();
        }
    });
    app.add(close, c1);

    JPanel cont = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    // cont.setSize(arg0, arg1);
    String a = "hello";
    JLabel text = new JLabel("<HtML>" + t);
    text.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    cont.setVisible(true);
    cont.setBackground(new Color(241, 242, 242));
    c1.gridx = 0;
    c1.gridy = 0;
    c1.weightx = 1.0f;
    c1.weighty = 1.0f;
    c1.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    c1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    cont.add(text, c1);
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy += 1;
    constraints.weightx = 2.5f;
    constraints.weighty = 2.5f;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    popup.add(cont, constraints);
    text.setFont(new Font("Comfortaa", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    text.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    header.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    popup.getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new Color(188, 188, 188)));

    popup.setVisible(true);
    Dimension s = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Insets th = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(popup.getGraphicsConfiguration());
    popup.setLocation(s.width - popup.getWidth() - 5, s.height - th.bottom - popup.getHeight() - 5);
    popup.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                popup.dispose();
            }

        }

    }.start();
}
```

Now when I click on the button once it works fine but for multiple button clicks multiple Jdialog pop-up appear
And only the last one gets disposed after 5s

So what changes I have to make in order to close every JDialog box

Comment: Edited,Please have a look

Comment: Use [`java.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of `Thread.sleep()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popup is not local to this method

```
popup = new JFrame();
```

as therefore this code is not threadsafe.

Each time you click, you are replacing the `popup` object with a newly created one, so `popup.dispose();` will dispose of the last one.